Direct sum of Hilbert space
I am a physics student who is not strong in mathematics.
I saw a statement in a paper on arxiv (https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02881, Fabio Anza, Christian Gogolin, and Marcus Huber):

Theorem 1. Let $\{|\psi_m \rangle \}^{M}_{m=1} \subset \mathcal{H} $ be a set of orthonormal vectors in A Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ of dimension $D$. Let $A = \sum^{n_A}_{j=1} a_j \Pi_j$ be an operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with $n_A \le D$ distinct eigenvalues $a_j$
and corresponding eigen-projectors $\Pi_j$. Decompose $\mathcal{H} = \oplus^{n_A}_{j=1} \mathcal{H}_{j}$ into a direct sum such that each $\mathcal{H}_j$ is the image of the corresponding $\Pi_j$ with dimension $D_j$. For each $j$ for which $D_j(D_j-1) \ge M+1$
there exists an orthonormal basis $\{|j,k \rangle\}^{D_j}_{k=1} \subset \mathcal{H}_j$ such that for all $k,m$, $|\langle \psi_m | j,k \rangle|^2 = \langle \psi_{m}|\Pi_j|\psi_{m}\rangle/D_j$.

I am not asking about the proof of this theorem, but I saw many terms in this statement for the first time and even after some study, my thoughts are not well organized. My questions are as follows:
If $A$ is expressed as $A = \sum^{n_A}_{j=1}a_j \Pi_j = \sum^{n_A}_{j=1} a_j \sum^{D_j}_{k=1} |j,k \rangle \langle j, k|$,

Is each basis set that composes $\mathcal{H}_j$ the same as $A$'s eigenbasis ${|j,k \rangle}$ (for $k = 1 \sim D_j$) which constitutes $\Pi_j$?

Is "image of the corresponding $\Pi_j$" correctly given as follows? 
For any arbitrary state $\psi \in \mathcal{H}$, it is the set of states given as $\Pi_j(\psi)$.

In a given finite-dimensional Hilbert space, is it always possible to divide the Hilbert space using a direct sum into $\mathcal{H} = \bigoplus^{n_A}_{j=1} \mathcal{H}_j$?

If the answer to question (3) is yes, are there no constraints on $A$? That is, is it possible to divide the Hilbert space using a theorem-like direct sum for any arbitrary operator $A$ acting in $\mathcal{H}$?

Are the propositions that the Hilbert space is represented as a direct sum and the system's Hamiltonian is represented in block diagonalized form independent of each other? (I believe they are.)

Is it always possible to represent the Hilbert space through a tensor product instead of a direct sum? That is, is it always possible to express it as $\mathcal{H} = \bigotimes^{N}_{j=1} \mathcal{H}_j$?


I apologize if the questions feel numerous and come off as unorganized. I would be truly grateful for answers to any of these questions.

The condition that $\mathcal{H}$ can be written as a direct sum of eigenspaces for $A$ is called diagonalizability. Not all operators fulfill this property, for example $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \ 0 & 0 \ \end{bmatrix}$ on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H} = \mathbb{C}^2$ is not diagonalizable.

Also the notation "$\otimes$" usually denotes the tensor product, not the direct product. These are completely different things. If one has finitely many factors, the direct product and the direct sum are the same thing.

Thanks @Smiley1000. I changed my original post with the tensor product.

The tensor product has nothing to do with the direct sum as already stated in the comments. It usually serves the purpose of treating systems composed of many subsystems: for example, when you have a set of $N$ identical particles the overall state space will be the tensor product of $N$ copies of the single particle state space $\mathcal{E}$ will be given by $\mathcal{E} = \bigotimes_{i}^{N} \mathcal{E}i$. Another example would be when the state kets present a space part and a spin part so that $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{E}{space} \otimes \mathcal{E}_{spin}$.

Thanks @Claudio.
In fact, I can easily imagine the case with tensor products, but I find it harder to understand direct sums. For instance, in your example of a system with N identical particles, how can we intuitively understand splitting the Hilbert space using a direct sum instead of a tensor product?
Could it be that using a direct sum is appropriate when N particles are completely non-interacting and therefore separated, and that representing the Hilbert space as a tensor product helps interpret situations where the N particles can interact in some way?

The direct sum usually appears when dealing with commuting operators: take the case of angular momentum: you can write for example $\mathcal{E} = \sum_{\oplus}^{} \mathcal{E}(k,j)$ when you fix the two indices $k,j$. What this means is that every subspace with a given $j$ will be invariant under the action of $J^2,J_z$ and in general every function $F(J)$. This means that the images of the basis vectors will remain in their respective subspaces. They don't mix different $k,j$, thus the block-diagonal representation.


If the subspace is one-dimensional, there is only one basis vector (up to scaling), so yes. If the subspace is more than one-dimensional, there are infinitely many choices of different bases.
I would say it is the set of all $φ ∈ \mathcal H$ that satisfies $φ = Π_j(ψ)$ for some $ψ ∈ \mathcal H$.
Yes. Also in infinite dimension. Take for example the linear span of some vectors. Then the Hilbert space is the direct sum of this span and its orthogonal complement.
I believe what you are after here is the notion of diagonalization: Is it always possible to write an operator as a (possibly infinite) sum of projectors with a factor (the factors being the eigenvalues)? For bounded operators (for example in finite dimension), this is true whenever the operator is normal. A self-adjoint operator is normal. In finite dimension, any Hermitian operator is self-adjoint. In physics, you often have self-adjoint operators, that correspond to things that can be measured. Then the eigenvalues are real. Coming back to your question: Not all operators can be diagonalized (that is, written as the mentioned sum)! Most cannot. Look up the spectral theorem!
They are connected. Each block in the Hamiltonian operator acts only on one subspace. That means that vectors in that subspace are mapped back to that subspace, using the block in the Hamiltonian.
It is always possible to do it in some sense, but it may not make much sense. It depends on the nature of the Hilbert space. Is it constructed in some kind of product of other spaces, and so on.


Hello. Thank you very much for your response. Since it appears there is a character limit in comments, I will divide my question into parts.
Regarding your answer to question 1, this is my understanding. Could you confirm if it's correct?
For $j$ where $d_j > 1$, the set ${|j,s \rangle}$ is not unique.
If there is one known set ${|j,s \rangle}$, another basis set can be formed through linear combinations.
Nonetheless, the bases that compose each subspaces $H_j$(though not unique) can be considered as the bases that constitute $A$'s projector $\Pi_j$, right?

Regarding your answer to question 5, it seems my question was not clear.
You mentioned that the Hilbert space can be expressed through a direct sum using the bases that form $A$'s projector.
However, when describing the Hamiltonian $H$(not the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$) using $A$'s eigenvectors (for example, ${|j,s\rangle}$), I believe they do not necessarily need
to be in the form of a block matrix obtained via direct sum.

From what I remember, to achieve this, one needs to find another operator $S$ that commutes with the Hamiltonian $H$, and constructing the Hamiltonian using their common eigenvectors
results in a block matrix form of the Hamiltonian $H$.
Thus, unless the considered $A$ commutes with $H$, expressing the Hilbert space as a direct sum using $A$'s projectors and having the Hamiltonian in a block matrix form are different, aren't they?
That was my understanding, and I wanted to ask if this thinking is correct.
If I am using any mathematically incorrect definitions, I apologize.

To your first question: Yes. To your second: It depends on the Hamiltonian operator. If it is created using the projectors of $A$, then they are connected. But it could of course be that $H$ is in block diagonal form with respect to some other basis.

To your third statement: I am not aware of this technique, but as I mentioned, it can certainly happen that $H$ has block diagonal form and $A$ is diagonal in two different bases, and then the corresponding subspaces are not in general connected.
